# Access Export as Spreadsheet Error - 3436 Failure creating file

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to put a time stamp in the file name of an Excel spreadsheet export out of Access.

Here's my code:

```vb
Private Sub Command31_Click()

Dim timeStamp As String
Dim XLfilePath As String

timeStamp = Now
XLfilePath = "C:\Folder\FileName - " & timeStamp & ".xls"

Debug.Print XLfilePath

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, , "MyAccessTable", XLfilePath, True

End Sub
```

For some reason I'm getting the following error:

```
Run-time error 3436
Failure creating file
```

Bit confused by this as the `Debug.Print` shows that the `XLfilePath` variable is holding:

```
C:\Folder\FileName - 23/04/2013 15:00:22.xls
```

...which is what I would expect.

`C:\Folder\` does already exist.

Comment: Just had a thought... can you even put ":" in a file name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That probably isn't a valid file name.  Instead of

```
timeStamp = Now
```

try:

```
timeStamp = Format(Now,"YYYYMMDD HHMMSS")
```

I believe this is the accepted standard for storing dates in filenames.  Also, when looking at the folder in Windows Explorer, your files are sorted by date by default.

Comment: Thanks. Feel dumb now. As usual, I spend an hour trying to figure something out, ask a question and then notice the problem within minutes of asking.

Answer (score 0):

I am using    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, , "Export Bid", strFileName, True
and getting different results ranging from runtime error 3436, quiet failure to create file, sometimes goes away with a compact/ repair, sometimes not.
Looks buggy to me.
July 2013  Using Office 2010